# Is there another way to click on the hyperlink in a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I am aware of the process to click a link on the spreadsheet that involves a small pop-up that says "Go to link..."  However, is there a way where the user of the sheet can directly click on the link without that pop-up?

I am trying to prepare a decision tree where, once a user selects a specific option and clicks it (which is a hyperlink) on the spreadsheet, he/she should be directed to the link.

e.g. What should you do if the product is not procured?

Options available for the users are (check whether the order status is one of the following):

1. Waiting for Inventory
2. Purchase order is generated
3. Product is listed Out of Stock

I have already created links for the 3 options, however I am unable to find a simpler way to directly click on the link.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

One alternative is to use Google Apps Script to create and open dialog box or custom side bar with the links.

**References**
[Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Apps - Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)